# Backing up my local database on google drive always creates a different file id

Tags: flutter, dart, google-drive-api

I am creating a to-do list app with flutter, and I want my users to be able to back-up their tasks on google drive.
This is the code I'm using:

```
// Create the file we want to upload.
ga.File fileToUpload = ga.File();
var file = await _localFile;
fileToUpload.parents = ["appDataFolder"];
fileToUpload.name = path.basename(file.absolute.path);

// Create a new back-up file on google drive.
var response = await drive.files.create(
  fileToUpload,
  uploadMedia: ga.Media(file.openRead(), file.lengthSync()),
);

// Get the file id.
   fileId = response.id;
```

The problem is that every time I get a different file id and I need to retrieve the file
from google drive with the same file id all the time and not with a different id every time.

I've tried using the update method instead of the create method:

```
ga.File fileToUpload = ga.File();
var file = await _localFile;
fileToUpload.parents = ["appDataFolder"];
fileToUpload.name = path.basename(file.absolute.path);
drive.files.update(fileToUpload, fileId);
```

But I get Unhandled Exception: DetailedApiRequestError(status: 403, message: The parents field is not directly writable in update requests. Use the addParents and removeParents parameters instead.)

I also tried to set the file id before using the create method:

```
fileToUpload.id = fileId;
      await drive.files.create(
        fileToUpload,
        uploadMedia: ga.Media(file.openRead(), file.lengthSync()),
      );
```

But then I get Unhandled Exception: DetailedApiRequestError(status: 400, message: The provided file ID is not usable.) 
Or that a file with that id is already exists.

So I've tried to delete the file from google drive and then create it again with the same id:

```
fileToUpload.id = fileId;
  drive.files.get(fileId).then((value) {
    if (value != null) {
      drive.files.delete(fileId).then((value) {
        drive.files.create(
          fileToUpload,
          uploadMedia: ga.Media(file.openRead(), file.lengthSync()),
        );
      });
    } else {
      drive.files.create(
        fileToUpload,
        uploadMedia: ga.Media(file.openRead(), file.lengthSync()),
      );
    }
  });
```

But then I also get Unhandled Exception: DetailedApiRequestError(status: 400, message: The provided file ID is not usable.)
Even though I'm using the same file id given by google drive for the original file.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to first check if the file is present in the drive by the name. Since there is not direct API to fetch a file with a name from google drive, you need to make use of the [`List api`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) and get the files first before checking their name

For that you can use the following query

```
{
  q: `'appDataFolder' in parents and trashed = false`
}
```

Once you get the response you can check if your file is present by name. If its get its id and trigger an [`update call`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) for the file.

Note: you do not pass `parents` key to upload but `addParents`

For media upload you would use the following url

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/fileId
```

If you do not find the file, you go by the method of creating a new one

```
// Create the file we want to upload.
ga.File fileToUpload = ga.File();
var file = await _localFile;
fileToUpload.parents = ["appDataFolder"];
fileToUpload.name = path.basename(file.absolute.path);

// Create a new back-up file on google drive.
var response = await drive.files.create(
  fileToUpload,
  uploadMedia: ga.Media(file.openRead(), file.lengthSync()),
);
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't see how it answer my question. As you can see on my third piece of code, I already check if the file exists on google drive by using the file id on google drive (I save the id on a server after the user creates the file on the first time). Your first 2 pieces of code are not in dart and I don't set a patch in my code, I just use the drive.files methods. Also, couldn't understand what "you do not pass parents key to upload but addParents" means.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the id of the file you have to use a generated id from google. That's why you're getting `the provided file ID is not usable`. Theres's a class you can use called [generateIds](https://pub.dev/documentation/googleapis/latest/googleapis.drive.v3/GeneratedIds-class.html) which you can use to create id's that can be used with create requests as you've done above. The Google Drive API developer website has a tool where you can make requests to the api. It's called "Try it now"(like postman)  For example, create the list of ids(just press execute) [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/generateIds?apix=true#try-it). Pick one of the ids and add it to the request body (in the request body box on the left side , press the plus sign to get the `id` key and add the generatedId) [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22enforceSingleParent%22%3Afalse%2C%22ignoreDefaultVisibility%22%3Afalse%2C%22keepRevisionForever%22%3Afalse%2C%22supportsAllDrives%22%3Afalse%2C%22supportsTeamDrives%22%3Afalse%2C%22useContentAsIndexableText%22%3Afalse%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%221SQQRElcHrgY9F52oSVgVY3v1AOYX639L%22%7D%7D#try-it) . You should get a 200 response with the id you sent with the request. It will also return a specific error message that you can handle if the id already exists (code 409)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I set the id I got from "Try it now" to the file I'm uploading, but when I try to create it on drive I get: DetailedApiRequestError(status: 403, message: Method not supported for files within the Application Data folder.). If I delete "fileToUpload.parents = ["appDataFolder"];" from my code I get: Unhandled Exception: DetailedApiRequestError(status: 403, message: The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.).  What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to specify the

`fileToUpload.parents = ["appDataFolder"];`

while updating a file in google drive